# Footer disappears on jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a PHP search results2.php page with several filters that are activated on click. When I land on that page for the first time everything is ok. But once I start filtering the page footers disappear.

Here's my jquery code...

```
$("#region, #producer, #wine_type").change(function(){
  var region_id = $("#region").val();
  var producer_id = $("#producer").val();
  var wine_type_id = $("#wine_type").val();
  var recipename = $("#recipename").val();
  var recipeid = $("#recipeid").val();
  $.ajax({      
      url:"results2.php",
      method:"GET",
      data: {region_id:region_id, producer_id:producer_id, wine_type_id:wine_type_id, recipename:recipename, recipeid:recipeid},
      success: function(data){       
        $("#filter_results").html(data);
      }
  });
})
```

On results.php I've got this...

```
    .....
<!-- results-area-->
    <div class="site-section bg-light" id="filter_results">     
      <?php include 'results2.php';?>
    </div>      
    <!-- results-area-end -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
        <div class="footer_top">
            <div class="container">
                ......
```

I've got other filter on that page but he's built differently. Whenever I use it the footer returns:

```
$("#search").on("select2:select", function(e) { 
  var selected_element = $("#search").val();
  var selected_element2 = $("#search").select2("data")[0].text; 
  window.location = "results.php?recipeid="+selected_element+"&recipename="+selected_element2+"";
 });
```

And here's my results2.php:

```
<?php
$recipeid = $_GET["recipeid"];
$recipename = $_GET["recipename"];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "motherwine";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
  $conn->set_charset("utf8");

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Erro: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

  //Display results with region filter ON
    $query ="SELECT wineid, wine_name, winetype_name, wine_img, producer_name, region_name, sponsored, recipe_name, recipeid, grade_name, nota
    from (select wine.id as wineid, wine_name, winetype_name, wine_img, producer.producer_name AS producer_name, region_name, sponsored, recipe_name, recipe.id as recipeid, round(avg(grade_id),0) as nota
    from wine, producer, winetype, region, recipe, rating, pairing
    where wine.id = pairing.wine_id and wine.winetype_id = winetype.id and wine.producer_id = producer.id and wine.region_id = region.id and
    recipe.id = pairing.recipe_id and 
    rating.pairing_id = pairing.id";

    ///group by wineid, wine_name, recipe_name) as temp, grade where grade.id = temp.nota order by sponsored desc, nota desc;

    $conditions = array();



    if (!empty($_GET["recipeid"]))  {
      $recipeid= $_GET["recipeid"];
      $conditions[] = " and recipe.id LIKE '%$recipeid%'";
    }

    if (!empty($_GET["region_id"]))  {
      $region_id= $_GET["region_id"];
      $conditions[] = " and wine.region_id LIKE '%$region_id'";
    }

    if (!empty($_GET["wine_type_id"]))  {
      $wine_type_id= $_GET["wine_type_id"];
      $conditions[] = " and winetype.id LIKE '%$wine_type_id%'";
    }

    if (!empty($_GET["producer_id"]))  {
      $producer_id= $_GET["producer_id"];
      $conditions[] = " and producer.id LIKE '%$producer_id%'";
    }

    $sql = $query; 

    if (count($conditions) > 0) {
      $sql .= implode(" ", $conditions);
    }

    $sql.= " group by wineid, wine_name, recipe_name) as temp, grade
    where grade.id = temp.nota order by sponsored desc, nota desc;";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo '<div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-start text-left mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-9" data-aos="fade">
          <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-black">Para acompanhar "'.$recipename.'", a mãe sugere...</h2>
        </div>      
      </div>


      <div class="row" data-aos="fade">';

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          if ($row["sponsored"] == 1){
            echo '<div class="col-md-12">            
              <div class="job-post-item bg-white p-4 d-block d-md-flex align-items-center">  
                <img id="wineID'.$row["wineid"].'" onclick="clicked('.$row["wineid"].')" class="img-fluid pr-2 resize_results" src=../backend/html/'.$row["wine_img"].' alt="'.$row["wine_name"].'"> 
                 <div class="mb-4 mb-md-0 mr-5">                  
                  <div class="job-post-item-header d-flex align-items-center">                  
                   <h2 class="mr-3 text-black h4">'.$row["wine_name"].'</h2>
                   <div class="badge-wrap">                     
                           <span class="bg-danger text-white badge py-2 px-4">Dica da mãe</span>                         
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="job-post-item-body d-block d-md-flex">
                    <div class="mr-3"><span class="fl-bigmug-line-portfolio23"></span><a href="#">'.$row["winetype_name"].'</a></div>
                    <div><span class="fl-bigmug-line-big104"></span><span>'.$row["region_name"].'</span>';
                    if ($row["nota"] < "0.49"){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                     ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "0.99"){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>                      
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "1.49"){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "1.99"){
                        echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "2.49" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "2.99" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "3.49" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "3.99" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "4.75" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>                      
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] <= "5.00" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>                      
                      ';}                 
                    else {
                        echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>';}
                    echo' </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>  
                 <div class="ml-auto">
                  <form action="details.php" method="get">
                   <a href="#" class="btn-favorite text-gray-500"></a>
                   <input type="hidden" name="op_wine" value='.$row["wineid"].'>
                   <input type="hidden" name="recipeid" value='.$row["recipeid"].'>
                   <input type="hidden" name="recipename" value="'.$_GET["recipename"].'">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary-results py-2">+ INFO</button>
                   </form>
                 </div>
              </div>

            </div>';}
            else {
              echo '<div class="col-md-12">            
              <div class="job-post-item bg-white p-4 d-block d-md-flex align-items-center">  
                <img id="wineID'.$row["wineid"].'" onclick="clicked('.$row["wineid"].')" class="img-fluid pr-2 resize_results" src=../backend/html/'.$row["wine_img"].' alt="'.$row["wine_name"].'"> 
                 <div class="mb-4 mb-md-0 mr-5">                  
                  <div class="job-post-item-header d-flex align-items-center">                  
                   <h2 class="mr-3 text-black h4">'.$row["wine_name"].'</h2>

                  </div>
                  <div class="job-post-item-body d-block d-md-flex">
                    <div class="mr-3"><span class="fl-bigmug-line-portfolio23"></span><a href="#">'.$row["winetype_name"].'</a></div>
                    <div><span class="fl-bigmug-line-big104"></span><span>'.$row["region_name"].'</span>';
                    if ($row["nota"] < "0.49"){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                     ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "0.99"){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>                      
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "1.49"){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "1.99"){
                        echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "2.49" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "2.99" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "3.49" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "3.99" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] < "4.75" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>                      
                      <span class="fa fa-star-half checked"></span>
                      ';}
                    else if ($row["nota"] <= "5.00" ){
                      echo '<span class="pl-4 fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>                      
                      ';}                 
                    else {
                        echo '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>';}
                    echo' </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>  
                 <div class="ml-auto">
                  <form action="details.php" method="get">
                   <a href="#" class="btn-favorite text-gray-500"></a>
                   <input type="hidden" name="op_wine" value='.$row["wineid"].'>
                   <input type="hidden" name="recipeid" value='.$row["recipeid"].'>
                   <input type="hidden" name="recipename" value="'.$_GET["recipename"].'">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary-results py-2">+ INFO</button>
                   </form>
                 </div>
              </div>

            </div>';
            }                
        }
    } else {
    echo "Desculpa filho, mas não tenho nenhuma sugestão de harmonização!";
    }


$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: where is results2.php code.. post that

Comment: I just edited the initial post and added it.

Comment: Don't you have any errors in PHP?

Comment: Nope, everything fine. This must be something related with CSS...

Comment: Problem solved. It was a container in the php echo that was causing this just deleted it and added it to results.php